# How to animate ListView item continuously even when the list is idle

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I want to animate the each item of `ListView` with different animations even when the list is idle i.e. it is not scrolling or fling state. I just know that it can be done by `Handler` and `Runnable` for continuous animation but its not working properly. Please suggest something for this.

Comment: What animation you need? You want to animate text like marquee?

Comment: There is ImageView in adapter and I want to animate that ImagView of each row with different unique animations in each row that too continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Add animation inside getview method of your custom adpater.Like this,

```
      @Override
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_row, parent, false);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);

       if(position==0)
{
        mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f);
       mAnimation.setDuration(10000);
       mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);//here we set repeat count to unlimited, so that the animation will run continuously 
       mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
       mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
       image.setAnimation(mAnimation);

}

else if(position==1)
{
//your second animation
}


     return rowView;
  }
```